# Parse server : module not found error on npm start command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, parse-platform, npm

I have installed **npm** on my local machine and setup **parse** example project.

Now I tried to run the project using ***npm start*** command but it gives an error at following line of code in **index.js** file.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI:  'mongodb://XXX',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '\\cloud\\main.js',
    appId: 'XXX',
    masterKey:  'XXX', 
    serverURL:  'http://localhost:1337/parse',  
});
```

When I run command as below

```
F:\parse-server-example-master>npm start
```

Its giving following error on command line

```
> parse-server-example@1.4.0 start F:\parse-server-example-master
> node index.js
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cloud/xxx.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\parse-server-example-master\cloud\main.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server-example
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\parse-server-example-master\np
m-debug.log
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: did you try to reinstall npm using >npm install ?

Comment: Please go through following 

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide

Comment: @JigneshPatel I have tried to reinstall but still having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code from what you have provided, try using / instead of \. Notice that the rest of your provided code uses forward slashes when defining paths. Also, try only using single slashes.

```
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '\\cloud\\main.js',
```